# How to create multiple instances of the "new" action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, form-for

On the `new` action page (let's say the model is called **Car**), I have a form where I can choose numbers from select menu (range 1-10). When I chose a number - let's say 5, I would need to display 5 forms where a visitor could put his information and save them (all 5 forms would needs to be sent out to the `create` action where would be saved into the table as 5 separate row).

How to do that? I will need to send probably these form as an array? And how to create in the new action array of **@car = Car.new**?

Thank you

Comment: I've done this with ajax/jquery, but if there's a simpler/rails-only way to do it, i'd love to know how.  +1

Answer (score 0):

There is one possible solution. For an example, lets consider you want to post two entries for car through a single form and each car model has got name and color field. Then:

HTML Form:

```
<form>

<h1>Car 1</h1>
Name: <input type="text" name="cars[index_0][name]" />
Color: <input type="text" name="cars[index_0][color]" />

<h1>Car 2</h1>
Name: <input type="text" name="cars[index_2][name]" />
Color: <input type="text" name="cars[index_2][color]" />

<input type=""submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Notice the "index_*" part added to name of every entry. In the "create" action, you can now iterate over these values in "params" and create the models. You would need to write a small helper and javascript code to achieve the modified field names or you can do that manually.

Comment: I need to create several forms on one page - in the `new` action.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want several "forms" and not combine all the required fields under one "form"?